# Why Carbon::createFromForma returns invalid date?

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

In laravel 8 app converting string datetime from string into datetime with carbon

```
$date= Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y H:m', ‘09/02/2021 05:56’, config('app.timezone') );


I got unexpected value in $date= ‘2025-08-02 05:00:00.000000’
```

but not current day as I expected and I do not see error in my format string?

Which way is correct ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
$date= Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y H:m', ‘09/02/2021 05:56’, config('app.timezone') );
```

Minute is `i`, not `m` in `'m/d/Y H:m'`.

*Also, you have apostrophes instead of quotes in `‘09/02/2021 05:56’`, but I guess that's only in this post since it would cause a PHP parse error.*